# Using article "a"

Tags: grammar, american-english, word-usage, sentence, articles

What is the correct sentence?

1. I'm neither a man nor a god
2. I'm neither man nor God
3. I'm neither a man nor God
4. I'm neither man nor a god

Comment: You can find examples of all four permutations in Google Books (plus some for *uncapitalised* "god" with no article). There are some differences of nuance depending on capitalisation and article use, but they're all potentially "correct". It's partly a stylistic choice, and partly a matter of what nuance you want to convey. Essentially, a Primarily Opinion-Based question.

Comment: Really depends on what you're trying to say. Big G *God* for the almighty, omnipotent, monotheistic deity of the Old Testament. Little g *god* for one of many gods with great (but not unlimited) power.

Comment: In "real" (spoken) language, **God** and **god** can't be distinguished, so there's no way to differentiate #3 as given (I'm not human and I'm not the monotheistic / Judeo-Christian god) from **#3a** - (...and I'm not *any* kind of "supernatural" being).

Comment: @FumbleFingers each permutation has a unique placement of "a" in use.

Comment: @Davo: I'm not sure what it *means* to include an article before capitalised proper noun **God**, but obviously that *can* actually be done in writing (the "poor relation" of real spoken language). Plus there's the permutation *neither man nor a god*, which is definitely valid, but not (yet?) present in OP's text.

Comment: I've seen situations where multiple (uppercase) Gods are recognized.

Comment: @Davo - I would be interested in any of those situations. Could you give examples and sources?

Comment: @Greybeard Personal experience - I'd be happy to post in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage-multi-layered-discourse-room) unless you prefer a new room.

Comment: @Davo: I'm not sure why chat would be necessary as it is directly connected to the question. If God is a unique name - identifying only the Judeo-Christian god - then this would be rather like having a plural of "Manchester in the North of England".

Comment: I know of pagan and heathen groups which use (capital-G) Gods, and so "a God" occurs in the documentation. If that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the capitalisation of God/god.

1. *I'm neither a man nor a god*-  **man** is a countable common noun; **god** is a countable common noun.
2. *I'm neither man nor God* - **man** is an uncountable common noun designating a class of object; **God** is an uncountable proper noun, i.e. a name.
3. *I'm neither a man nor God* - **man** is a countable common noun; **God** is an uncountable proper noun, i.e. a name.
4. *I'm neither man nor a god* - **man** is an uncountable common noun designating a class of object; **god** is a countable common noun.

You may wish to add

*I'm neither man nor god* in which both **man** and **god** are uncountable nouns.

Comment: Yet another permutation: [*Buddha is often described as **neither a man nor god** nor a gandharva nor a yaksha*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22described+as+neither+a+man+nor+god%22). I'm a bit dubious about the "validity" of that particular combination - especially given the article reappears for ***a gandharva*** and ***a yaksha***. But I wouldn't like to unilaterally rule against it being "correct".